# how can i convert object into an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got object from firebase like this way and i need to convert into an array i used a foreach with map but i didn't get success. i got 0 length of an array.

```
0: {id: "1", name: "Fever"}
1: {id: "2", name: "Cough"}
2: {id: "3", name: "Headache"}
3: {id: "4", name: "Stomach Pain"}
```

i used below method but it's not working

```
let result = [];

arr.forEach(item => {
  let resObj = result.find(resObj => resObj.Name === item.Name);
  resObj ? resObj.Count++ : result.push({'Name':item.Name, 'Value': item.Value, 'Count': 1});
});

console.log(result);
```

i need the output like this

```
[
{id: "1", name: "Fever"},{id: "2", name: "Cough"},{id: "3", name: "Headache"},{id: "4", name: "Stomach Pain"}
]
```

Comment: Can you please add what your expected result is to the question?

Comment: You are using `'Value': item.Value` in your code but in your array you have only two keys: `id` & `name`. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NickParsons i want like this way [
{id: "1", name: "Fever"},{id: "2", name: "Cough"},{id: "3", name: "Headache"},{id: "4", name: "Stomach Pain"}
]

Comment: @vivekmanavadariya how does that differ from your input/what does your input look like?

Comment: i get in object and i need into an array within this bracket []

Comment: So you have an object which looks like `{0: {id: "1", name: "Fever"},
1: {id: "2", name: "Cough"},
2: {id: "3", name: "Headache"},
3: {id: "4", name: "Stomach Pain"}}` and you want it to be an array?

Comment: Yes like this way

Comment: Try `const result = Object.values(your_object)`

Comment: okay let me try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
let obj = {
  0: {
    id: "1",
    name: "Fever"
  },
  1: {
    id: "2",
    name: "Cough"
  },
  2: {
    id: "3",
    name: "Headache"
  },
  3: {
    id: "4",
    name: "Stomach Pain"
  }
};
let arr = [];
for (let key in obj) {
  arr.push(obj[key]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

The for ... in loop iterates over each obj key and push all the values of the obj in the arr.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Object.values()`, however, this doesn't guarantee an array with the same keys from your object. For example, if you had this situation:

```
{
  0: {id: "2", name: "Cough"},
  2: {id: "1", name: "Fever"} 
}
```

... then your result could look like (missing index 2):

```
[{id: "1", name: "Fever"}, {id: "2", name: "Cough"}]
```

thus, it doesn't abide by the index values provided in the object, but takes the values from the object and creates an array from those values. Instead, if you want to take the object's keys into account, you can merge the object with an array using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/assign), giving an empty value if a particular index is missing. The following also guarantees the order will be based on the index value:

```js
const obj = {0: {id: "1", name: "Fever"}, 1: {id: "2", name: "Cough"}, 2: {id: "3", name: "Headache"}, 3: {id: "4", name: "Stomach Pain"}};

console.log(Object.assign([], obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Object.values`

```js
let obj = {
  0: {
    id: "1",
    name: "Fever"
  },
  1: {
    id: "2",
    name: "Cough"
  },
  2: {
    id: "3",
    name: "Headache"
  },
  3: {
    id: "4",
    name: "Stomach Pain"
  }
};

const res = Object.values(obj);

console.log(res);
```